# How to train a NLP when there is same key word is repeating in "LUIS" and "QNA Makers" using dispatcher

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

Below is my issue:
I have sample utterance trained in LUIS and QnA maker as below when I ask question 2 it is picking up top-scoring intent from  LUIS, How can I train LUIS and QnA with these type of scenarios?
LUIS Utterance:
1.what are the status of my expense
etc

QNA Utterance:
2.How to raise an issue for my expense
etc

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your app, I think the issue is around how you are using LUIS and QnA. LUIS should be used to detect the user's intent based on the utterance(s). In this case, both example utterances are about "expenses". LUIS, if the model is structured and trained correctly, would detect this and return the "expenses" intent.

The returned intent would indicate which knowledge base to direct the actual question to and, thus, a returned response to the question asked.

As for flow, there are a number of ways you could construct this. It's mostly about order.

You could construct this as a series of waterfall steps. One step to parse the response in LUIS and a second step to return an answer from QnA dependent on the LUIS response. In this example, I say 'Hello' which LUIS recognizes as a 'greeting' intent. When that intent is returned and matched, then the statement is passed to QnA which returns the "question" response: 'Hi!'.

Hope of help!

```js
async luisStep ( stepContext ) {
  if ( stepContext.context.activity.text ) {
    const stepResults = stepContext.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();

    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( `You said: ${ stepResults }` );

    const recognizerResult = await this.recognizer.recognize( stepContext.context );
    let intent = await LuisRecognizer.topIntent( recognizerResult );

  if ( intent ) {
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity( `Luis recognized: ${ intent }` );
      return stepContext.next( recognizerResult );
    } else {
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity( 'No LUIS intent was found.' );
      return stepContext.next( recognizerResult );
    }
  } else {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( 'Moving to the QnA step' );
    return await stepContext.next();
  }
}

async qnaStep ( stepContext ) {
  const resultDetails = stepContext.result;
  const topScoringIntent = stepContext.result.luisResult.topScoringIntent;

  if ( topScoringIntent.intent === 'Greeting' ) {
    let qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(stepContext.context);

    if(qnaResults[0]) {
      stepContext.context.sendActivity(`QnA response: ${qnaResults[0].answer}`)
    }

    return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
  } else {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( 'There was an error retrieving QnA results.' );
  }
  return await stepContext.next();
}
```

[image]